# Why does R# say "Expression is always false" with this code?

Tags: c#, null, resharper, conditional-statements

Resharper flags two "Redundancies in Code" in InitializeObjects() below:

```
public string InitializeObjects()
{
    string RetVal = null; // <-- Value assigned is not used in any execution path
    try
    {
        dbConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=PlatypusBO;Password=PlatypusBO;Data Source="
            + Database + ";Persist Security Info=False;Jet OLEDB:System database=" + Workgroup);
        dbConnection.Open();

        RetVal = FastLookup(ref dbConnection, "setting_value", "t_settings", "key_setting='TableVersion'").ToString();

        if((RetVal == "") || (RetVal == null)) // <- Resharper says, "Expression is always false"
            RetVal = "0.0.0.0";
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        RetVal = null;
    }
    return RetVal;
}

private object FastLookup(ref System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection tConn, string fldName, string tName, string strFilter)
{
    if (tConn == null) 
    {
        return "";
    }

    object RetVal = "";
    string sqlCriteria = "";

    if (strFilter != "") 
    {
        sqlCriteria = " WHERE " + strFilter;
    }

    if (tConn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) 
    {
        tConn.Open();
    }

    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand catCMD = tConn.CreateCommand();
    catCMD.CommandText = "SELECT " + fldName + " FROM " + tName + sqlCriteria;

    try 
    {
        using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader myReader = catCMD.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (myReader != null && myReader.Read())
            {
                RetVal = myReader.IsDBNull(0) ? "" : myReader.GetValue(0);
            }
            else
            {
                RetVal = "";
            }
        }
        //myReader.Close();
    } 
    catch (Exception) 
    {
        RetVal = "";
    } 
    finally 
    {
        catCMD.Dispose();
    }

    return RetVal;
}
```

...and I don't know why; it seems like the first one, "Value assigned is not used in any execution path" is not true, because there is a subsequent test to see if RetVal is null.

The second one ("Expression is always false") doesn't make sense to me either, as RetVal can be either one of those vals (an empty string or null), as it is assigned both at points in the code.

I'm (99.9999%) sure R# is right, but why is it right?

### UPDATE

Changing it to this muzzles R#:

```
public string InitializeObjects()
{
    string RetVal;
    try
    {
        dbConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=DuckbilledPBO;Password=DuckbilledPBO;Data Source="
            + Database + ";Persist Security Info=False;Jet OLEDB:System database=" + Workgroup);
        dbConnection.Open();

        RetVal = FastLookup(ref dbConnection, "setting_value", "t_settings", "key_setting='TableVersion'");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(RetVal))
            RetVal = "0.0.0.0";
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        RetVal = null;
    }
    return RetVal;
}

private string FastLookup(ref System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection tConn, string fldName, string tName, string strFilter)
{
    if (tConn == null) 
    {
        return "";
    }

    string RetVal;
    string sqlCriteria = "";

    if (strFilter != "") 
    {
        sqlCriteria = " WHERE " + strFilter;
    }

    if (tConn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) 
    {
        tConn.Open();
    }

    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand catCMD = tConn.CreateCommand();
    catCMD.CommandText = "SELECT " + fldName + " FROM " + tName + sqlCriteria;

    try 
    {
        using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader myReader = catCMD.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (myReader != null && myReader.Read())
            {
                RetVal = myReader.IsDBNull(0) ? "" : myReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                RetVal = "";
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception) 
    {
        RetVal = "";
    } 
    finally 
    {
        catCMD.Dispose();
    }

    return RetVal;
}
```

Comment: It could be basing it off the return type of `FastLookup`. What happens if you change it to `string`? Also, `FastLookup` never returns `null`.. it returns an empty string.. which could also be confusing it.

Comment: Side note: posting whole bunch of comments is not useful, especially if comments are wrong "returns:The requested value or NULL, if not found", but `null` never returned from the function...

Comment: Is it possible that it will return null if there is an uncaught exception?

Comment: @ClayShannon there is no return value when function throws an exception... So all cases where it can return value when exception thrown are covered by `catch (Exception) {RetVal = "";}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as mentioned in the comment, the return type of your method is the problem, by using object as the return type and comparing that to a empty string you're doing a reference comparison.

To illustrate, here is a simple example where Resharper will tell you the exact same thing.

```
object oneString = " ";
string newString=new string(' ',1);
if (newString == oneString)
{
    //doesn't happen
}
```

One solution would be to change your return type to string or cast the returned object to string.

Comment: Something is wrong.. I was unusually correct for this time of morning... :)

Comment: @Simon Whitehead: Indeed you where. Had to try it myself to be certain. :)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Morning? Where are you, Rota? Here in the lettuce capital of the world it's going on 4 pm.

Comment: @shriek: If I cast the return type to string, a la: 
RetVal = (string)FastLookup(Bla),
R# tells me "Type cast is redundant"

Comment: @ClayShannon Australia :)